# What does it mean to be a co-author?

Tags: publications, research-process, authorship, research-undergraduate

What does acting as a "co-author" entail, and how common is it for first year undergraduate students to be added as co-authors to a paper being prepared by a professor?

Comment: Please ask [one question per post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1204/11365). You can [edit] this post to remove one sub-question, then post it as a new question.

Comment: Voting to close because the question is too broad to be particularly answerable. I think this is *far* from off-topic just because the author happens not to be a graduate student.

Answer (score 5):

Almost any published work has one or more people listed as authors: they are those people who made a significant contribution to the creation of the work.  If there is more than one author, they are called co-authors, and one might say they *co-authored* the work.  Usage like "become co-authored into a paper" would be non-standard and perhaps non-grammatical; one would instead say that a person became a co-author of the paper (typically for having contributed to it in a significant way).